# .htaccess - redirects after a certain point in the file not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Would be so very grateful if someone can help me with this... I have been using a .htaccess 301 redirect file on my personal side business website for a while now however after a certain point in the file, the redirects simply do not work (returning a 200 in Rex Swain's http header tool).

I've looked through the file with a fine toothcomb and where the redirects stop working there are no issues at all (e.g. the urs are exactly as they should be). Really do not know why they would stop redirecting after a certain point?

Does anyone have any thoughts / recommendations? For anyone that would be willing to help I could send the file across.

Look forward to hearing from you,
Motley

Here's the code, the last line is the redirect that doesn't work. All before this work completely fine. There are other redirects after the last one (ive just not shown them), which also do not redirect. There is also a blank line at the end of the file.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain/$1 [L,R=301]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# index.html to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Redirect examples**

```
Redirect 301 /spas/alexander-house/overnight-packages http://www.domain/spas/alexander-house/spa-breaks

Redirect 301 /spas/alexander-house/day-packages http://www.domain/spas/alexander-house/spa-days

Redirect 301 /spas/alexander-house/weekend-packages http://www.domain/spas/alexander-house/spa-weekends

Redirect 301 /spas/armathwaite-hall/overnight-packages http://www.domain/spas/armathwaite-hall/spa-breaks

Redirect 301 /spas/armathwaite-hall/day-packages.html http://www.domain/spas/armathwaite-hall/spa-days

Redirect 301 /spas/armathwaite-hall/weekend-packages http://www.domain/spas/armathwaite-hall/spa-weekends

Redirect 301 /spas/billesley-manor/overnight-packages http://www.domain/spas/billesley-manor/spa-breaks

Redirect 301 /spas/billesley-manor/day-packages http://www.domain/spas/billesley-manor/spa-days

Redirect 301 /spas/billesley-manor/weekend-packages http://www.domain/spas/billesley-manor/spa-weekends

Redirect 301 /spas/bishopstrow-house/overnight-packages http://www.domain/spas/bishopstrow-house/spa-breaks

Redirect 301 /spas/bishopstrow-house/day-packages http://www.domain/spas/bishopstrow-house/spa-days

Redirect 301 /spas/bishopstrow-house/weekend-packages http://www.domain/spas/bishopstrow-house/spa-weekends

Redirect 301 /spas/bovey-castle/overnight-packages http://www.domain/spas/bovey-castle/spa-breaks

Redirect 301 /spas/bovey-castle/day-packages http://www.domain/spas/bovey-castle/spa-days

Redirect 301 /spas/bovey-castle/weekend-packages http://www.domain/spas/bovey-castle/spa-weekends

Redirect 301 /spas/castlemartyr/overnight-packages http://www.domain/spas/castlemartyr/spa-breaks

Redirect 301 /spas/castlemartyr/day-packages http://www.domain/spas/castlemartyr/spa-days

Redirect 301 /spas/castlemartyr/weekend-packages http://www.domain/spas/castlemartyr/spa-weekends

Redirect 301 /spas/celtic-manor/overnight-packages http://www.domain/spas/celtic-manor/spa-breaks

Redirect 301 /spas/celtic-manor/day-packages http://www.domain/spas/celtic-manor/spa-days

Redirect 301 /spas/celtic-manor/weekend-packages http://www.domain/spas/celtic-manor/spa-weekends

Redirect 301 /spas/chewton-glen/overnight-packages http://www.domain/spas/chewton-glen/spa-breaks
```

Comment: There has to be some redirect logic in your application. When redirecting from `/spas/alexander-house/overnight-packages` to  `http://www.domain/spas/alexander-house/spa-breaks`, where does the `spa-breaks` come from?

Comment: Ah those are simple static redirects supported by the `mod_alias` module http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: Sorry Michael, what does this mean then? To answer your first comment above, the spa-breaks is a page within the /alexander house/ directory. I've removed the page /overnight-packages/ page from my local directory, but it's still on the remote server

Answer (score 0):

Did you try moving the Redirect to a different line in the .htaccess file? If the redirects following the new line location of Redirect 301 /spas/chewton-glen/overnight-packages http://www.domain/spas/chewton-glen/spa-breaks aren't working now then you know it is this Redirect alone that is causing the problem. Did you try removing this one redirect and see if the preceding redirects now work? I bet it has something to do with the chewton-glen directory?

Comment: I've tried removing this redirect - all of the redirects after this point do not work, so I don't think I can put it down to this one particular redirect. Seems to be more like a certain point in the file - I don't think there's a limit to the number you can have here?

Comment: I don't think there is a limit to the number of re-directs normally, but maybe you could comment out the working ones and see if that is the case. I am at a loss for words to be honest. I think Michael may be onto something